# Setting android:lines on TextInputEditText not working

Tags: android, android-layout, text, multiline, android-textinputedittext

Do anyone know how to show Total Lines prior display when using `TextInputEditText` and `TextInputLayout`? I don't have this problem when using the normal EditText without the `TextInputLayout`. This is my sample code :

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/input_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_small"
                app:counterEnabled="true"
                app:counterMaxLength="1000"
                app:counterOverflowTextAppearance="@style/TextLimitError"
                app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.App.TextInputLayout"
                app:theme="@style/TextInputLayoutStyle">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/input"
                    style="@style/TextInputEditTextStyle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="hint text"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                    android:lines="5"
                    android:maxLength="1000"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

My goal is to have the same effect like html `textarea` when we're setting the `rows` attribute.

[image]

This is what i got when setting the `android:lines` on the `TextInputEditText`. It leave a blank empty space between the floating label and the first letter that i typed.

[image]

Comment: Try `android:maxLines`.

Comment: @ADM it's not working

Comment: `TextInputEditText` is child of `EditText` ultimately . It should work . Maybe culprit is `android:maxLength`.

Comment: How about `android:minLines` ?

Comment: Can you tell me about the exact error ?

Comment: @LinLin setting android:minLines the start TextInputEditText area will be bigger, but it leaves empty space between the start character and the floating text that can't be cleared, refer to this screenshoot [link](http://i63.tinypic.com/14wrrjt.png)

Comment: @ADM removing the android:maxlength not change the result also, please look at this screenshoot [link](http://i63.tinypic.com/14wrrjt.png)

Comment: @YahyaMukhtar i have edited the question, please take a look to the attached picture

Comment: @2MuchSmoke Do you want to see hint? I mean floating label

Comment: @LinLin yes i need the floating label to show, and the first letter that i typed not leaving empty space between the floating label and the letter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try `android:gravity="top|left"` below this may help

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
          android:id="@+id/input_layout"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_small"
          app:counterEnabled="true"
          app:counterMaxLength="1000"
          app:counterOverflowTextAppearance="@style/TextLimitError"
          app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.App.TextInputLayout"
          app:theme="@style/TextInputLayoutStyle">

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/input"
                            style="@style/TextInputEditTextStyle"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="top|left"
                            android:hint="hint text"
                            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                            android:lines="3"
                            android:maxLines="5"
                            android:minLines="3"
                            android:maxLength="1000"
                            android:singleLine="false"
                            android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
 </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: This also worked for me, but I have to specify `android:lines` and provide a fixed number there. Do you know of a way to make it accept a variable amount of lines, preferably wrapping the text?

Comment: @Dambakk are you talking about providing dynamic number of lines..... if yes then try to set lines programatically.

Comment: Yes, that works fine, but what about when the user enters more text? The text should wrap into new lines but it doesnt. Do you know why or how to achieve that behavior?

Comment: Oh, I just had to set `isSingleLine = false`. Embarrassing.. :)

Comment: ohh lol :) happy to help you and will update my code with your suggestion...

Answer (score 6):

set android:gravity="top|left"  is working ，like below:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/notesValue"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left|top"
                android:hint="@string/mlNote"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
                android:lines="3" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```